# why do I get syntax error when using f.select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my code:

```
<%= f.select :question, :part_number, :options_for_select => ([1..5]), options = { :include_blank => true } %>
```

I keep getting this error:

> syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC ...= { :include_blank
>   => true } ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat ...

Comment: no need to specify `options=` in your syntax again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since that I use select and not collection_select, there is no need to specify the object (:question).

So for anyone who comes to this problem, here is the solution:

```
<%= f.select :part_number, (1..5), { :include_blank => true } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the Rails docs can be a bit confusing, but if you're using the `select` form helper within a `form_for @question` block, you don't specify the object. Thus, your code would need to change to

```
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.select :part_number, options_for_select((1..5)), include_blank: true %>
  ...
<% end %>
```